# How to make a value based reference in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have an excel sheet which fetches the values from an API and these values changes in real time, I mean the row position changes on daily basis.
Problem is when I reference a particular row to write a formula in another sheet and its value changes tomorrow I get the wrong value because it is a cell-based reference and not a value based.
How to handle such scenario?

Comment: Please add a specific example.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer as written. The solution might involve named ranges but that is just a guess. If you actually gave details, it might be possible to do something better than guessing. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Hello sancho,I am using this API to get the data to excel using web "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0" This gives a set of 1000+ rows and it changes the row positions all the time based on the market condition.

Answer (score 0):

Excel has several worksheet functions for that purpose. The most popular is VLOOKUP, where you know the column in which your value resides but not the row - precisely what you seem to explain. Google for "Excel VLOOKUP" or simply look in Excel's own Help.